# Java Parsing xml document from url

Tags: java, xml, parsing, url

When parsing an URL, I got this error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog
```

What should be improved in the code?
There is also required link.

```
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, MalformedURLException {
        String link = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";
        URL url = new URL(link);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc =  builder.parse(url.openStream());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that URL gives you XML?

Comment: By your url I see JSON, not XML

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please could you check the exact response type is coming for URL you provided , as I see the Json response type in browser as well as in postman even if i am sending content type as "application/xml". So dont parse the response using xml parser as your response is coming in JSON format. You need to use json parser for parsing Json object.